# Challenging Integration involving cosecant and cosine

Tags: integration, contest-math, indefinite-integrals

The question is

$\int \frac{cosec^2x -2020}{cos^{2020}x}$=$\frac{Af(x)^B}{g(x)^{2020}}$+c where f($\frac{\pi}{6}$)=$\sqrt3$

Then, the value of $A^2+B^2+f(-\frac{\pi}{4}$)=....

I tried converting into tangent form , but it's not making sense further, I tried by by parts formula,  but that also makes it quite long, I am not getting any ideas I am now trying this for much time.

It must be of some specific form , but it is not hiting.

I would like to have some hints to carry on...it's a high school level question, so I expect it to be easy, once it strikes. :-)

Comment: What is $g(x)$?

Comment: @Kenta : Don't know,  maybe we will get after integration.

Comment: Split the integral into two (the difference in the numerator). Just use substitution or differential method for both integrals noting that $\frac{1}{\cos^2 x} = \tan^2 x +1$ and $\frac{dx}{\cos^2 x} = d(\tan x) $.

Comment: Thats awkward because you have to compute $$\int \frac{du}{(u^2+1)^{1010}} - 2020 \int \frac{dx}{\cos^{2020} x}$$ The first integral is by recursion (you can find a formula). The other integral is by integration by parts, which trickier than former one. Good luck :)

Comment: @Rover how can there possibly be a unique solution if $g(x)$ is not specified beforehand?

Comment: @Kenta S : it can be as it's given f($\frac{\pi}{6}$)=$\sqrt3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "form" of the solution is already provided to you. Upon analysis, it seems to me that the first step should be to multiply both the numerator and denominator by $cos^{2020} x$.

Why? because, the derivative of the expression given should be the integrand. Recall the quotient rule, which says that the denominator should be *squared*. So, having $cos^{4040}x$ draws us one step closer to transforming the integrand into the derivative of the given expression.

The integrand after this is:

$$\dfrac{cosec^2x cos^{2020}x - 2020cos^{2020}x}{cos^{4040}x}$$
=$$\dfrac{d/dx(-cotx) cos^{2020}x - 2020cos^{2019}x*cosx}{cos^{4040}x}$$
=$$\dfrac{d/dx(-cotx) cos^{2020}x - 2020cos^{2019}x*(-sinx)(-cotx)}{cos^{4040}x}$$
=$$\dfrac{d/dx(-cotx) cos^{2020}x - d/dx(cos^{2020}x)(-cotx)}{cos^{4040}x}$$
=$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{-cotx}{cos^{2020}x}$$

(from the quotient rule $\dfrac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}= (u/v)'$)

From the fundamental theorem of calculus, the integral is therefore:
$$\dfrac{-cotx}{cos^{2020}x}$$

Which means $A= -1$, $B=1$, $f= cot x$ . The value of the expression is therefore $2+(-1)=1.$